# Whether a total order set of size $n$ has the fewest endomorphisms among posets of size $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, posets

A function $f: P \to P$ is an endomorphism iff for any $x \le y$ in the poset $P$ , $f(x) \le f(y)$. So among posets of size $n$, whether the total order set $[n]$ (with the usual ordering) has the fewest endomorphisms?

Answer (score 11):

No. The zig-zag poset on 4 elements has only 31 endomorphism, whereas the total order has 35 endomorphisms.

I added the number of automorphisms and endomorphisms of a poset to http://www.findstat.org, should be visible shortly.

Update:

To make things a little bit clearer, note that adding more covering relations may increase the number of endomorphisms.  Consider the two posets below, then the map sending $[0,1,2,3]$ to $[0,0,0,2]$ is not a poset endomorphism of the fence, but it is a poset endomorphism of the second poset.

[image: Zig Zag]
[image: other]

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/St000634, more information and references are very welcome!

Comment: The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_(mathematics) seems to be a good candidate for the poset with the minimal number of endomorphisms, with the exception of the fence on 3 elements with 11 endomorphisms, where the chain has only 10.  The minima I got so far are $1,3,10,31,99$.

Comment: Surprise: the poset on 6 elements with the minimal number of endomorphisms (234) is *not* the fence (which has 275).   Instead, it is the poset with cover relations $[3, 5], [3, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2], [0, 2], [0, 4]$.  I hope I did not make a programming mistake - this is rather weird.

Comment: The 234 is confirmed by my program.

Comment: But I would describe it as {1, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 6}, a cycle with directions alternating.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen: is your program available - and perhaps a bit more efficient than mine?

Comment: My back of the envelope calculation suggests that as $n$ grows large, the $n$-element fence should have $\Theta(n(\sqrt2+1)^n)$ endomorphisms, whereas for even $n$, the $n$-element “closed fence” (like the $6$-element one above) only $\Theta(\sqrt n(\sqrt 2+1)^n)$, so the latter should be better for all large enough (and even) $n$.

Comment: (For odd $n$, a similar bound should hold for the closed fence with $n-1$ elements with an extra element splitting one of the edges.)

Comment: @Martin Rubey: In Mathematica I put endoQ[f_List]:=AllTrue[rel,MemberQ[rel,f[[#1]]]&] then rel = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6}, {1, 2}, {3, 
   2}, {3, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {1, 6}} then Length[Select[Tuples[Range[6], 6], endoQ[#] &]]. One must not start with 0.

Comment: @Martin Rubey: Recursion works better:  rel ={{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 10}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}, {5, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 6}, {7, 6}, {7, 7}, {7, 8}, {8, 8}, {9, 8}, {9, 9}, {9, 10}, {10, 10}}; max = Max[rel]; Do[down[i] = Select[rel, Max[#] == i &], {i, max}];  checkdown[f_List] := AllTrue[down[Length[f]], MemberQ[rel, f[[#1]]] &];  num[{}] := Sum[num[{i}], {i, max}];  num[f_List] := If[checkdown[f],If[Length[f] == max,1,Sum[num[Append[f, i]], {i, max}]],0];  num[{}] gives 10030.

Comment: I see the number "234" in Table V of this paper: Farley, Jonathan David, "The number of order-preserving maps between fences and crowns,"
Order 12 (1995), no. 1, 5–44.

Answer (score -2):

For posets with less than five elements, the total order is the unique poset with one unique endomorphism, but on 5 elements,
there are in total 3 posets with only one endomorphism:
the poset with edges
$$
12, 13, 24, 35, 45 \text{ and }
13, 14, 24, 25, 35
$$

**Old unrelated answer:**

Won't the unique poset $P$ on $n$ elements with no relations whatsoever 
admit the maximal number of endomorphisms?

Namely, any $P \to P$ is an endomorphism,
since any pair of elements are unrelated, and they are also mapped to a pair of unrelated elements. Or, if you do not allow two different elements with no relation to be mapped to the same element, then you get the $n!$ permutations.

Comment: This is not right. The number of endomorphisms of $[n]$ is "$n$ multichoose $n$" or in other words $\binom{2n-1}{n}$.

Comment: (Endomorphisms of $[n]$ clearly correspond to sequences $1\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \cdots \leq x_n \leq n$: we just map $i$ to $x_i$.)

Comment: @Per : Uh, no.  Every poset has at least one endomorphism which is the identity and (when having more than one element) one constant map to each element.  Endomorphisms do not preserve incompatibility necessarily.  Gerhard "Let's Get This Order Straight" Paseman, 2016.10.23.

Comment: [2] has 3 endomorphisms. You can always map all elements to a fixed element.

Comment: Ah, my bad - I did not consider $a\leq a$ as true for all elements in a poset.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense: you were looking at *strictly* order-preserving maps

Comment: It would be great to have the number of strictly order-preserving maps in findstat, too!

Comment: This is now http://www.findstat.org/StatisticsDatabase/St000635